# Spark window over timestamp range

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working on a problem using Spark 3.2.4 with Zeppelin 0.10.1 in the pyspark env.

| id | start_time_in_millis | end_time_in_millis |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 2 | 3 | 5 |
| 3 | 6 | 7 |

For the above table, I am trying to collect, for each row, all ids that overlaps duration.

For example,

```
id = 1, collect = {1,2}
id = 2, collect = {1,2}
id = 3, collect = {3}
```

Additionally, I also want to introduce a delta value. So, intervals that are within the delta value are also collected. For the above example, with delta = 1,

```
id = 1, collect = {1,2}
id = 2, collect = {1,2,3}
id = 3, collect = {2,3}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I found one solution but i am doing self non equi join to find matching records so i assume that it is not very performant and may casue some problems with big datasets

Sample code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

x = [(1, 1, 3), (2, 3, 5), (3, 6, 7)]

df = spark.createDataFrame(x, schema=["id", "start", "end"]).orderBy("start")
df2 = (
    df.withColumnRenamed("id", "id_right")
    .withColumnRenamed("start", "start_right")
    .withColumnRenamed("end", "end_right")
)
delta = 1

joined = df.join(
    df2,
    (df["start"] <= df2["end_right"]) & (df["end"] >= df2["start_right"])
    | (df["start"] + delta <= df2["end_right"]) & (df["end"] + delta >= df2["start_right"]),
    "left",
)

finalDf = joined.groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_set(F.col("id_right")))
finalDf.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+---------------------+
| id|collect_set(id_right)|
+---+---------------------+
|  3|                  [3]|
|  2|            [1, 2, 3]|
|  1|               [1, 2]|
+---+---------------------+
```

Physical plan:

```
== Physical Plan ==
CollectLimit (10)
+- ObjectHashAggregate (9)
   +- Exchange (8)
      +- ObjectHashAggregate (7)
         +- * Project (6)
            +- * BroadcastNestedLoopJoin LeftOuter BuildRight (5)
               :- * Scan ExistingRDD (1)
               +- BroadcastExchange (4)
                  +- * Project (3)
                     +- * Scan ExistingRDD (2)
```

As you can see there is NestedLoopJoin (due to non equi join) which i dont like but i dont see other solution for now, maybe someone else will post something more performant. I think that you can also check my solution on your data and maybe in case of problems we will figure out something else if there will be such a need